# Boost lock-free queue is triggering clang's thread sanitizer

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, queue, lock-free

I created a lock-free object pool using [boost's lock-free queue](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/lockfree.html), version 1.68. While it seems to be working fine, I keep getting these warnings from clang's thread sanitizer in the function `pop()`.

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=32452)
  Write of size 2 at 0x7b4400081e00 by thread T54 (mutexes: write M3349, write M3517):
    #0 boost::lockfree::detail::tagged_index::set_index(unsigned short) /opt/boost/boost/lockfree/detail/freelist.hpp:292:15 (Exchange-tests+0xb37c09)
    #1 boost::lockfree::detail::fixed_size_freelist<boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::node, boost::lockfree::detail::runtime_sized_freelist_storage<boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::node, std::allocator<boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::node> > >::deallocate_impl(unsigned short) /opt/boost/boost/lockfree/detail/freelist.hpp:592:33 (Exchange-tests+0xb3c31f)
    #2 void boost::lockfree::detail::fixed_size_freelist<boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::node, boost::lockfree::detail::runtime_sized_freelist_storage<boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::node, std::allocator<boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::node> > >::deallocate<true>(unsigned short) /opt/boost/boost/lockfree/detail/freelist.hpp:580:13 (Exchange-tests+0xb3c23b)
    #3 void boost::lockfree::detail::fixed_size_freelist<boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::node, boost::lockfree::detail::runtime_sized_freelist_storage<boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::node, std::allocator<boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::node> > >::destruct<true>(boost::lockfree::detail::tagged_index) /opt/boost/boost/lockfree/detail/freelist.hpp:478:9 (Exchange-tests+0xb3c1d7)
    #4 bool boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::pop<unsigned long>(unsigned long&) /opt/boost/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:418:39 (Exchange-tests+0xb3c102)
    #5 boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::pop(unsigned long&) /opt/boost/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:375:16 (Exchange-tests+0xb3bda8)
    #6 ObjectPool<MarketsController>::borrowObj() 
...

  Previous atomic read of size 4 at 0x7b4400081e00 by thread T52 (mutexes: write M3339, write M3518):
    #0 __tsan_atomic32_load /tmp/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_interface_atomic.cc:535:3 (Exchange-tests+0x503e11)
    #1 std::atomic<boost::lockfree::detail::tagged_index>::load(std::memory_order) const /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../include/c++/7.3.0/atomic:250:2 (Exchange-tests+0xb37e97)
    #2 bool boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::pop<unsigned long>(unsigned long&) /opt/boost/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:394:54 (Exchange-tests+0xb3beca)
    #3 boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned long, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<true> >::pop(unsigned long&) /opt/boost/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:375:16 (Exchange-tests+0xb3bda8)
    #4 ObjectPool<MController>::borrowObj() 
...
```

Following boost's code I see that this [`boost/lockfree/detail/freelist.hpp:292`](https://github.com/boostorg/lockfree/blob/master/include/boost/lockfree/detail/freelist.hpp#L292):

```
void set_index(index_t i)
{
    index = i; // this line
}
```

and this [`boost/lockfree/queue.hpp:394:54`](https://github.com/boostorg/lockfree/blob/master/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp):

```
tagged_node_handle next = head_ptr->next.load(memory_order_acquire);
```

I'm not sure how to react to this, but how worried should I be? Is this a bug in boost or the sanitizer? Or maybe something wrong I did?

Comment: What type is ´index´?

Comment: @Surt You can see it in the link of the source code I provided. `typedef boost::uint16_t index_t;`.

Comment: My gut feeling is that it should be an atomic, as it counts some free list, try changing it to an atomic type and see if sanitizer is happy. And it is already mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909951/if-this-is-not-a-bug-in-boostlockfreedetailfreelist-what-am-i-missing-her but I think the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Surt I tried. It doesn't seem to be that simple. Changing that to `boost::atomic<index_t>` creates an avalanche of compile errors.

Comment: @Surt - you mistake. the `index` inside `freelist_node::tagged_index`/ not need to be atomic. for what ? nobody access it in concurrent. this block is allocated and de-allocated for exclusive access. this is special (stack based) heap memory block. and in boost code no error. error in *ThreadSanitizer*. this is feature of `pop` implementation - when multiple threads in concurrent try `pop` from queue or stack. possible access element which already was pop by another thread. but all what need here, that memory of this element still valid

Comment: and answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909951/if-this-is-not-a-bug-in-boostlockfreedetailfreelist-what-am-i-missing-her is correct

Comment: @rbmm does that mean that if two threads simultaneous want to update the freelist there is no problem or is there a freelist for each thread so its not a problem.

Comment: @Surt - `freelist_node` is allocated for concrete thread (when it allocated `node`). this is exclusive access structure. never multiple threads in concurent **modify** the `freelist_node`. this is really special heap block, allocated during `push` (when we allocate new `node`) and free during `pop` (when we free `node`). here not need any atomic. however during `pop` operation we need access node, which we not own. because this is warning. but all what we need here - memory for accessed node (which we not own) must be valid. boost give this (`node`  free to pool, memory still valid)

Comment: @Surt here (in stack trace) situation when 2 thread in concurrent call `pop` and try pop the **same** (`0x7b4400081e00`) node. thread *T54* already pop node and free it to pool. during this the `index` is updated (but free can not be call in concurrent, only owner of block (who pop it) can call free). at the same time `T52` try pop this (`0x7b4400081e00`) node and need read it data (index) for get pointer to next node. this is well known situation for `pop`

Comment: @Surt - make `index` (util part of heap block) have no sense. let it be atomic - we anyway access in this case memory block which already deallocated (or in process of this). but this not lead to errors, because we fail in `head_.compare_exchange_weak`. all what need for algorithm - memory of `node` must be valid. must not be exception when we read it. wrong value - here not problem

Comment: `freelist_node` this is service part of allocated memory block, before user data. like any allocated heap memory block, only owner of block can call free for it. can not be free from several threads in concurrent.

Comment: @rbmm OK, the missing part was that the freelist was thread local and therefore not subject to data races.

Comment: @Surt - no, this not thread local in any sense. this is part of heap block. problem here (from ThreadSanitizer view only) that one thread access (read) memory, while another delete it. *T54* call `node = pop(); delete node;` while *T52* call `node->next` (this of course in generic sense).

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] test case that can reproduce this thread-sanitizer warning?  With code and command-line options for how you built + tested it.  Otherwise we can't rule out the possibility you're somehow using the library or tools wrong.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's impossible that I did something wrong because of the nature of the stack trace I presented, to which I still remain skeptic and I accept criticism there. But please, don't just ask me for an MCVE just because it's easy to ask for it (while I understand you have the right to do so). Please take a look at the stack trace and tell me how something I did could've caused the issue, then I'll be happy to provide an MCVE.

Comment: @PeterCordes - really reproduce this is easy under debugger. all what we need - push how minimum one element to queue and 2 threads which in concurrent call pop  (need control thread execution under debugger). first thread we need stop at [*393 line*](https://github.com/boostorg/lockfree/blob/master/include/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp#L393) after this let another thread call pop. after it execute *L418*, we can suspend it and resume first thread. `head_ptr` already "free" by second thread

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - this is not your bug, but *ThreadSanitizer* (i dont know how it work). but in pop operation really possible that we access already deleted (or under deletion node). in delete process - index inside node will be updated. another thread at same time read this index, for get pointer to next node. look like as bug, but here unusual situation. not race and bug

Comment: this more easy visible if use stack container. suspend first thread at [*500*](https://github.com/boostorg/lockfree/blob/master/include/boost/lockfree/stack.hpp#L500), than run another thread, which pop element (this will be exactly `node * old_tos_pointer` from thread suspended at *500*, and then resume first thread - it will access already free node (`tagged_node_handle new_tos(old_tos_pointer->next, old_tos.get_next_tag());`).

Comment: @RbMm Thanks for the explanation.